# QueryBuilder Doctrine Left Join

Tags: doctrine, typo3, query-builder

Need some help to translate this correctly.

Old:

```php
$categories = $GLOBALS["TYPO3_DB"]->exec_SELECTgetRows(
    'c.uid, c.id, c.name AS categoryName, c.tstamp', 
    'tx_registration_domain_model_product AS p LEFT JOIN ' 
      . 'tx_registration_domain_model_category AS c ON p.category = c.uid', 
    "p.hidden = 0 AND p.deleted =0 AND c.hidden = 0 "
      . "AND c.deleted =0 AND c.name != '' AND p.material = '"
      . $materialUid . "'", 
    'p.category'
);
```

New:

```php
$catConstraints = [
    $queryBuilder->expr()->neq(
        'c.name',
        $queryBuilder->createNamedParameter('')
    ),
    $queryBuilder->expr()->eq(
        'p.material',
        $queryBuilder->createNamedParameter($materialUid, \PDO::PARAM_INT)
    )
];

$categories = $queryBuilder
    ->select('c.uid', 'c.id', 'c.name', 'c.tstamp')
    ->from($productsTable, 'p')
    ->leftJoin(
        'p',
        $categoriesTable,
        'c',
        $queryBuilder->expr()->eq(
            'p.category',
            $queryBuilder->quoteIdentifier('c.uid')
        )
    )
    ->where(...$catConstraints)
    ->groupBy('p.category')
    ->executeQuery();
```

> The given alias 'c' is not unique in FROM and JOIN clause table. The currently registered aliases are: tx_registration_domain_model_material, p, c.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax looks correct so far, which can also be looked up here:

https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/ApiOverview/Database/QueryBuilder/Index.html#join-innerjoin-rightjoin-and-leftjoin

```php
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Database\Connection;

// SELECT `sys_language`.`uid`, `sys_language`.`title`
// FROM `sys_language`
// INNER JOIN `pages` `p`
//     ON `p`.`sys_language_uid` = `sys_language`.`uid`
// WHERE
//     (`p`.`uid` = 42)
//     AND (
//          (`p`.`deleted` = 0)
//          AND (
//                  (`sys_language`.`hidden` = 0)
//              AND (`overlay`.`hidden` =  0)
//          )
//          AND (`p`.`starttime` <= 1475591280)
//          AND (
//                  (`p`.`endtime` = 0)
//               OR (`overlay`.`endtime` > 1475591280))
//     )
$queryBuilder = $this->connectionPool
    ->getQueryBuilderForTable('sys_language');
$result = $queryBuilder
    ->select('sys_language.uid', 'sys_language.title')
    ->from('sys_language')
    ->join(
        'sys_language',
        'pages',
        'p',
        $queryBuilder->expr()->eq(
            'p.sys_language_uid',
            $queryBuilder->quoteIdentifier('sys_language.uid')
        )
    )
    ->where(
        $queryBuilder->expr()->eq(
            'p.uid',
            $queryBuilder->createNamedParameter(42, Connection::PARAM_INT)
        )
    )
    ->executeQuery();
```

From doctrine/dbal code, this should also work with your code:

```php
$qb = $conn->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('u.id', 'p.id')
    ->from('users', 'u')
    ->leftJoin('u', 'phonenumbers', 'p', 'u.id = p.user_id');
```

You are using two variables, one for the `fromTableName ($productsTable)` and one for the `joinTableName ($categoriesTable)`. Reading the error message:

> The given alias 'c' is not unique in FROM and JOIN clause table. The currently registered aliases are: tx_registration_domain_model_material, p, c.

and the fact that there is only one table and two aliases listed, that you either have:

- reused the same QueryBuilder instance `$queryBuilder` to do a second query, along with a second `from` statement (which is not supported)
- either `$productsTable` or `$categoriesTable` or both is/are an empty string

So ensure that you really create a new QueryBuilder instance for the new query, e.g. like so:

```php
$queryBuilder = $connection->createQueryBuilder();
// or $queryBuilder = $connection->getQueryBuilder();
// depending on the TYPO3 version and doctrine/dbal version
$catConstraints = [ /*...*/ ];
```

and recheck the contents of the two variables.

**Edit:**

Using the `\PDO` constants should be avoided. Instead use the `Connection::PARAM_*` class constants instead. That would be
more future proof, because doctrine/dbal 4.0 would not support
integer types anymore and these are replaced with `PHP Enums`.
From TYPO3 core side, it's planned to redefine the `Connection::PARAM_*` constants with the enums in TYPO3 v13 together with the `doctrine/dbal 4.0 upgrade`.

Or you can use the doctrine `ParamType::*` contants in TYPO3 v12 and doctrine v12 which are replaced by PHP Enums with doctrine/dbal 4.0. Would advice to use the TYPO3 wrapping constants.

Comment: Aaah thanks a lot for the sharp analysis, I indeed re-used the Querybuilder instance.